# Oracle/SQL - Multiple Records Into One [string aggregation]

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, string-aggregation

I realize this is a ridiculous request, but what I'm trying to do is pull multiple records back into a single column along with some literal text.

So given a table like this

```
REGION  CITY    SID
-------------------
1   Chicago     1234
1   Palatine    567
1   Algonquin   234
1   Wauconda    987
```

I would like to see back a single record with a column, other columns like region are fine, but a single column like this

```
<option value="1234">Chicago</option><option value="567">Palatine</option><option value="234">Algonquin</option><option value="987">Wauconda</option>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?  I'm running Oracle 9i and cannot do this in PL/SQL

---

Okay the table format has changed a bit, but the idea is the same

```
COUNTRY STORECODE   STORE_NAME
------------------------------
USA     1234        Chicago
USA     567         Palatine
CAN     987         Toronto
```

So I found this code going through the links listed

```
SELECT COUNTRY,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(STORECODE,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS COUNTRY_HTML
FROM   (SELECT COUNTRY,
               STORECODE,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY STORECODE) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY STORECODE) -1 AS prev
        FROM   tablename)
GROUP BY COUNTRY
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND COUNTRY = PRIOR COUNTRY
START WITH curr = 1;
```

And when I run it I see this output

```
COUNTRY COUNTRY_HTML
--------------------
USA     1234,567
CAN     987
```

My thought was simply to have the inner select pull from another select where I do my concat of the STORECODE and STORE_NAME along with the html required like this...

```
SELECT COUNTRY,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(RECORD_HTML,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS COUNTRY_HTML
FROM   (SELECT COUNTRY,
               RECORD_HTML,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY RECORD_HTML) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY RECORD_HTML) -1 AS prev
        FROM   (SELECT COUNTRY, '<option value="' || STORECODE || '">' || STORE_NAME || '</option>' AS RECORD_HTML FROM tablename))
GROUP BY COUNTRY
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND COUNTRY = PRIOR COUNTRY
START WITH curr = 1;
```

While our front end environment does accept the query when I try to review the results I get a error: the resource is invalid.  You may need to re-create of fix the query before viewing.

I know that error probably isn't helpful, but any ideas why my version isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really, really sure you can't do this in your application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to generate concatenated strings in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531001/fast-way-to-generate-concatenated-strings-in-oracle)

Comment: WW. I'm certainly going to push for it, but in the event we cannot or simply as a learning exercise it would be great to be able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's disgusting but you could do something like this:

```
select replace(blah2,',','')
  from ( select wm_concat(blah) as blah2
           from ( select '<option value="' || sid || '">' || city || '</option>' as blah
                    from my_table
                         )
                 )
```

Comment: I know you said it is disgusting, but it is also subject to XML injection.  You need to XML-escape sid and city if you take this approach.

Comment: And just to be more difficult - any thoughts on doing this without using wm_concat()

Comment: @dscl, please note I do not condone doing this. Just pointing it out as a solution. You should take [WW's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14663/ww) comment on board. As you're on 9i I would suggest `stragg`, which I [proved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823509/how-to-concatenate-strings/8825034#8825034) is identically limiting to `wm_concat`, so sorry... Other ways would be worse.

Answer (score -2):

Have you played around with DBMS_XMLGEN?

Comment: Is this really an answer? Shouldn't it be just a comment?

Comment: Would you rather I reworded this as "DBMS_XMLGEN will let you do what you're looking for"?

Comment: I'm not criticising, just that what you wrote is more of a comment than a hepful answer. Just mentioning DBMS_XMLGEN wouldn't be hugely helpful either, a brief explanation of the specifics would qualify IMHO.

Answer (score -3):

You can create an aggregate function in Oracle, see documentations.