# sql: Aggregate / gather strings within one column (with a single query)

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Oracle SQL query that aggregates multiple rows into one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row)
>   [Fast way to generate concatenated strings in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531001/fast-way-to-generate-concatenated-strings-in-oracle)

An oracle sql newbie question

i have a following table:

```
id1 A
id1 B
id1 C
id1 A
id2 A
id3 B
id3 A
```

What I want to get

```
id1 A,B,C
id2 A
id3 B,A
```

I cannot use loops, i have to get it with just a query

I use an Oracle DB v10 (I know it's important because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954511/oracle-pl-sql-results-into-one-string)).

Comment: hm I guess you wrongly used the "similar" word. To me you want to group as long as you get different values, and if X are the same, skipp them and keep A ( row 4+5 in your given rows)

Comment: search for concatenate column values Oracle ....

Comment: @Lamak almost. Thank you very much anyway.
The difference: I would like to now have any the duplicates in the right column.

Comment: I would also like to add a site with several possible solutions: [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

Comment: Dupiicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4686543/1509264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use wm_concat(fieldname) to solve the purpose.
So your query will be :

```
SELECT attr1, wm_concat(attr2) FROM YourTable GROUP BY field2;
```

And If you want **Duplicates** to be removed then

```
SELECT attr1, wm_concat(distinct attr2) FROM YourTable GROUP BY field2;
```

Comment: `wm_concat` doesn't allow me to use several tables in one query...