# Is there another command for wm_concat in oracle 9i?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have a table containing dept id, employee names and date of joining. I want to get a list of all the employees who joined on a given day in a given dept.

`wm_concat` is not working.

Comment: What version of Oracle? Can you show your query and the *exact* error message?

Comment: I have Oracle 9i. I have not figured out how to do this in 9i.

Comment: Please provide your error message

Comment: See [**Oracle String Aggregation Techniques**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/) and [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php), `WM_CONCAT` is not supported.

> WM_CONCAT is an undocumented function and as such is not supported by
>   Oracle for user applications

You can use a user defined aggregate function described in that link.

Answer (score 1):

Try `wmsys.wm_concat` (10g+) or `listagg` (11g+)

Comment: I have Oracle 9i. Can you please suggest something for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sys.STRAGG`

```
SELECT department_id, 
       hire_date, 
       TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM sys.STRAGG(last_name || ',')) names
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id, hire_date
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1d22/3)**

Comment: This is trimming the results, in some cases this could be not acceptable

Answer (score 1):

See the [String Aggregation Techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) page.

For 9i, you can declare a UDAG function as in the page cited:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
     RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER
);
/



CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, ','), ',');
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ',' || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_agg (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
/
```

And using it is like:

```
SELECT deptno, string_agg(ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;
```

You can also try the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531001/fast-way-to-generate-concatenated-strings-in-oracle)(which is slow if you have big table)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Look for example of ROW_NUMBER() and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH functions in Oracle 9i on that page.

If PL/SQL is an option then TABLE_TO_COMMA Procedures may work: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_util.htm#ARPLS73271

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use `WM_CONCAT` since it is an **undocumented feature** and it has been **removed** from the latest **12c version**. Any application which has had been relying on `wm_concat` function will not work once upgraded to `12c`. See [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SELECT object_name
  2  FROM dba_objects
  3  WHERE owner='WMSYS'
  4  AND object_name LIKE 'WM\_%' ESCAPE '\';

OBJECT_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
WM_REPLICATION_INFO
WM_RDIFF
WM_PERIOD
WM_PERIOD
WM_OVERLAPS
WM_MEETS
WM_LESSTHAN
WM_LDIFF
WM_INTERSECTION
WM_INSTALLATION
WM_GREATERTHAN
WM_EVENTS_INFO
WM_ERROR
WM_ERROR
WM_EQUALS
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_DDL_UTIL
WM_CONTAINS
WM_COMPRESS_BATCH_SIZES
WM_COMPRESSIBLE_TABLES

20 rows selected.
```

You will receive an “**invalid identifier**” error:

```
SQL> SELECT banner FROM v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    12.1.0.1.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp;
SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) FROM emp
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier
```

Therefore, there is no point relying on an **undocumented feature** which is no more made available in latest versions.

There are various **[string aggregation techniques](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/oracle-string-aggregation-techniques/)**:

- **LISTAGG** in 11gR2 and up

For example,

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

- **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions in 9i and up

For example,

```
SELECT deptno,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
FROM   (SELECT deptno,
               ename,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
GROUP BY deptno
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND deptno = PRIOR deptno
START WITH curr = 1;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```

- User-defined aggregate function **STRAGG** described in [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402).
- **COLLECT** function in 10g and up

A few good examples by Tim Hall [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).